# Dynamically Created Elements

Tags: javascript, dynamically-generated

So I am trying to create an expense tracker that has a list of dynamically created options.

The user will be able to:

- add a new expense
- select a category
- add a name for the expense, and then
- put how much the expense is.

I have everything working, **except for I would like to display the categories with the total amount of money budgeted for each category**.

Right now I have 9 categories. If a uses has 2 expenses with the same category, for example *"Health & Fitness"*, I would like that Category to show up on the left side in a `DIV` that displays the total amount budgeted. If there are other categories like *"Auto & Transport"*, I would like that to display as well with the total amount budgeted. I can't seem to figure out how to separate the totals based on the category selected.

```
var addListItem = document.getElementById("add-more");

addListItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  createNewItem();
});

//Display Month and Day
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;

today = mm + "/" + dd;
document.getElementById("current-date").innerHTML = today;

//Creates new elements
function createNewItem() {
  var u = document.getElementById("full-item-list");
  var l = document.createElement("li");
  var elinput = document.createElement('input');
  var select = document.createElement('select');
  var option1 = document.createElement('option');
  var option2 = document.createElement('option');
  var option3 = document.createElement('option');
  var option4 = document.createElement('option');
  var option5 = document.createElement('option');
  var option6 = document.createElement('option');
  var option7 = document.createElement('option');
  var option8 = document.createElement('option');
  var option9 = document.createElement('option');
  var option10 = document.createElement('option');
  var o1 = document.createTextNode('Category');
  var o2 = document.createTextNode('Auto & Transport');
  var o3 = document.createTextNode('Bills & Utilities');
  var o4 = document.createTextNode('Health & Fitness');
  var o5 = document.createTextNode('Home');
  var o6 = document.createTextNode('Personal Care');
  var o7 = document.createTextNode('Pets');
  var o8 = document.createTextNode('Shopping');
  var o9 = document.createTextNode('Entertainment');
  var o10 = document.createTextNode('Investments');
  var expenseName = document.createElement('input');
  var icon = document.createElement('img');

  option1.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
  option1.setAttribute('selected', 'true');

  option1.appendChild(o1);
  option2.appendChild(o2);
  option2.setAttribute('name', 'testName');
  option3.appendChild(o3);
  option3.setAttribute('name', 'testName2');
  option4.appendChild(o4);
  option5.appendChild(o5);
  option6.appendChild(o6);
  option7.appendChild(o7);
  option8.appendChild(o8);
  option9.appendChild(o9);
  option10.appendChild(o10);

  select.setAttribute('type', 'select');
  select.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Select a Category');
  select.appendChild(option1);
  select.appendChild(option2);
  select.appendChild(option3);
  select.appendChild(option4);
  select.appendChild(option5);
  select.appendChild(option6);
  select.appendChild(option7);
  select.appendChild(option8);
  select.appendChild(option9);
  select.appendChild(option10);

  expenseName.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  expenseName.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Expense name');
  expenseName.setAttribute('class', 'expense-input-name')
  expenseName.setAttribute('name', 'totalExpense');

  elinput.setAttribute('type', 'number');
  elinput.setAttribute('class', 'li-input');
  elinput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter amount');
  elinput.setAttribute('name', 'qty');

  l.setAttribute('class', 'list-item');
  l.setAttribute('name', 'li-name');
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'remove-icon');
  icon.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/375261/System_Delete.ico');
  icon.setAttribute("id", "icon-id");
  icon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  thaticon(e);
    }, false);

  l.appendChild(select);
  l.appendChild(expenseName);
  l.appendChild(elinput);
  l.appendChild(icon);
  u.appendChild(l);
}

//Deletes elements
function thaticon(e) {
  console.log("test");
  var el = e.target;
  var elListItem= el.parentNode;
  elFullList = elListItem.parentNode;
  elFullList.removeChild(elListItem);
}

//Calculates and displays results
function displayResult() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName("qty");
  var wage = document.getElementById("inputWage").value;
  var jumboDiv = document.getElementById("jumbo-results").style.display="block";
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total Expenses: $" + tot.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "Left Over: $" + ((wage - tot).toFixed(2));
}

//Resets and clears entire entry
function resetForm() {
  var jumboDiv = document.getElementById("jumbo-results").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("full-item-list").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("inputWage").value = "";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = "";
}

//Displays the selected categories by user with the total sum for each one
function displayCategory() {

}

//Capture screen shots
/*function captureScreen() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  });
}*/
```

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but if you create such a project you might want take a look on frameworks like vue or svelte. They are not bloatware like react, angular or ember that force you into certain project structures, but will make such dynamic things way easier.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a data structure to store the category information and use that to construct your HTML elements.

The following code constructs a simple `select` element without any additional attributes.

```
var optionsArray = ['Category',
                    'Auto & Transport', 
                    'Bills & Utilities',
                    'Health & Fitness',
                    'Home',
                    'Personal Care',
                    'Pets',
                    'Shopping',
                    'Entertainment',
                    'Investments'];

var selectElem = document.createElement('select');
selectElem.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Select a Category');
// iterate through the array of options
optionsArray.forEach(function(text){
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  var optionText = document.createTextNode(text);
  option.appendChild(optionText);
  selectElem.appendChild(option);
});
// selectElem is ready to append to the DOM
```

This can be improved upon by changing the elements in the array to objects and using the attributes if required.

e.g.

```
var optionsArray = ['Category',
                    'Auto & Transport', 
                    {
                      'itemText' : 'Bills & Utilities',
                      'itemDisabled' : true,
                      'itemSelected' : true
                    },
                    'Health & Fitness',
                    'Home',
                    'Personal Care',
                    'Pets',
                    'Shopping',
                    'Entertainment',
                    'Investments'];

var selectElem = document.createElement('select');
selectElem.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Select a Category');
// iterate through the array of options
optionsArray.forEach(function(item){
  var text = (typeof(item) === 'string') ? item : item.itemText;
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  var optionText = document.createTextNode(text);
  option.appendChild(optionText);
  if (typeof(item) === 'object') {
    // handle custom attributes
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key){
      switch(key) {
        case 'itemDisabled' :
          if (item[key]) {
            option.setAttribute('disabled', true);
          }
          break;
        case 'itemSelected' :
          if (item[key]) {
            option.setAttribute('selected', true);
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    });
  }
  selectElem.appendChild(option);
});
// selectElem is ready to append to the DOM
```

The calculations for the category totals would need to be done using a data structure such as an array of objects. Iterate through the array, calculating the totals before adding the desired information to the HTML.